# C# WPF Dynamic Scaling with MinHight/MinWidth Set to Auto

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The title pretty much describes what I am looking for. I have found answers that are close but not quite what I need. I am hoping someone can explain how to do this or point me in the right direction.

Current setup:
I have multiple user controls. Each contain a grid that has 5 rows and 3 columns. First row definition is set to Height="Auto" and the rest are Height="*". First column definition is set to Width="Auto" and the others are set to Width="*". I do not want the first row and first column to ever change size but I would like to have the rest of the grid scale.

Question:
I am trying to create a window, which contains a grid, that will dynamically size. The grid contains user controls stated above and each row and column in the window is set to *. I do not want any element in the window to size below what is required for the inner controls (i.e. I do want a button control change sizes but it should never become smaller then Auto width or height). Is there a way to allow for this scalability but do not get any smaller then what the controls requires (ideally within the xaml)?

I don't remember the exact CSS syntax, but I was hoping xaml had something similar to the way CSS sizes content equal to the size of characters on the screen (i.e. Min-Width: 1.5m;)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted the first row and column to be a static size then don't set them to auto, set the actual size then for the rest of the columns/rows you could use * so they all remain equal

Comment: Right but when you set the rest as *, they will scale down to the point where you cannot read text within the control. My questions is how do you set the minimum width and height equal the the minimum size required to show all of the control's content